# An unexpected token "EXCEPTION" was found In PL/SQL(DB2)

Tags: plsql, db2

I am Wrting a Stored Function As below in db2.

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION moc_enddate( IN v_date    VARCHAR(6),
                                        IN v_message VARCHAR(20)) returns DATE
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v_temp DATE;
    DECLARE v_end_date DATE;
    DECLARE v_temp_string VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT '01';

      SET v_temp_string = v_temp_string
          || v_date;
      SET v_temp = to_date(v_temp_string,'DDMMYYYY');
      SET v_end_date = (v_temp + 19 days);
      RETURN v_end_date;
  EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
          SET v_message = 'SqlDataException';
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          SET v_message = 'OTHER';
        END;
```

But I am getting the following Exception.

```
ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "EXCEPTION" was found following "RN V_END_MOC_DATE; ".  Expected tokens may include.
"<psm_case>".
```

Comment: Did you enable support for PL/SQL (which is Oracle's procedural language) in DB2? I think it is not enabled by default (and only available in 9.7 and later)

Comment: I think it is enabled becouse if i will remove Exception Block then its working . I wanted to Handle Exception , and in this case its not working.

Comment: You are mixing PL/SQL (your exception declaration) and DB2 SQL PL (the rest of your code). Choose one and stick to it. In the DB2 SQL PL you use `DECLARE HANDLER` for exception handlers.

Comment: You're also attempting to modify the value of an input parameter of a scalar user-defined function (UDF), which is not going to work. To do that, you'd need to create a procedure, not a function, and make v_message an `INOUT` parameter.

Comment: Request you to share a sample DB2 plsql procedure code with proper exception handling. Being new to this I am not much aware...

Comment: Also please let me know how to enable PL/SQL support in db2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you are using DB2 SQL PL instead of PL/SQL. There is a difference between these languages. If it's the case, the following condition should work:

```sql
create or replace procedure CreatePlants
begin
   declare sqlstate   char(5)       default '00000';
   declare ErrorMsg   varchar(96);

   declare exit handler for sqlexception
      begin
         set ErrorMsg = 'SQLSTATE=' concat sqlstate;
         signal sqlstate '99001'
            set message_text = ErrorMsg;
      end;

   create table plants
   ( ID dec(3),  Location  varchar(16),
   primary key (ID));

   label on table plants is 'Plant master';

   insert into plants values
   (  1,  'Lost Angeles'),
   (  2,  'New Yolk'),
   (  3,  'Last Vegas');
end
```

For more references see:

[Error Handling in SQL PL, Part 1](https://www.itjungle.com/2017/06/12/guru-error-handling-sql-pl-part-1/)

[Determine The State Of The Error](https://www.itjungle.com/2016/09/13/fhg091316-story02/)